# VS Code cant open Excel using win32com

Tags: python, win32com

i have tried the following code in Python Interpreter, Thonny IDE, Wing IDE, and double clicking the .py file... it opens Excel with no issues...

BUT, when i try to run this within VS Code **or** if i cmd into folder location and run file from cmd...  the outline of Excel window flashes for 1 second then closes (no errors are outputted)

I dont know how to troubleshoot it.  Im new to VS Code, but hopefully the cmd will give someone a clue that experienced experienced something similar...

```
import win32com.client as win32
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.Visible = True
```

Comment: Could that be because IDLE is waiting for you? i.e. it doesn't close the IDLE application and thereby cleaning up on Excel instance? How about putting `input("press enter to exit")` to pause the program completion ?

Comment: try using try: catch block You might catch some exception.